# Match exactly (and only) the pattern I specify in a grep command

Tags: regex, grep, parsing

Usually, [**grep**](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) searches for all lines containing a match for the pattern/parameter I specify.

I would like to match just the pattern (i.e. not the whole line).

So, if a file contains the lines:

```
We said that we'll come.
Unfortunately, we were delayed.
Now, we're on our way.
Didn't I say we'd come?
```

I want to find all contractions starting with "we" (regex pattern: `we\'[a-z]+/i`); I'm looking for the output:

```
we'll
we're
we'd
```

How do I do this (with **grep** or another Unix/Windows command-line tool)?

Comment: I took a look at the 'grep' man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep and nothing suggested what you want is possible. You might want to try using 'sed' or 'awk'.  If really feeling adventurous, even write a 2-5 line script in PERL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-o` option:

```
grep -E -i -o "we'[a-z]+" file.txt
```

Note that this is not universally portable to all `grep` implementations, though.

Comment: My **grep** has it, so that works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer Perl for something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open FH, "< parse.txt" or die $!;

while(<FH>)
{
    while($_ =~ /\b(we\'\w+)\b/g)
    {
        print $1."\n";
    }
}

close FH;
```

Input text:

```
Some text we're test we'll why we're.
More text we'll we're.
Test.
```

Output:

```
we're
we'll
we're
we'll
we're
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the filename, you should make it accept a filename as an argument and work as a filter. Also, I believe the OP wanted case-insensitive.

Comment: @Dennis it was an example...